# C++ ifstream type error

Tags: c++, gcc, filestream, ifstream

I want to read the content of a file with c++. Im using ifstream, but here is an error at compiling:

Code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream script;
script.open("main.py");
const char *programm;
if (script.is_open()) {
    while (!script.eof()) {
        script >> programm;
    }
}
script.close();
```

And the Error:

```
main.cpp:8:1: error: 'script' does not name a type
 script.open("main.py");
 ^
main.cpp:10:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'if'
 if (script.is_open()) {
 ^
```

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: You need to put your operations into a function!

Comment: CAn you show code what i must do? im not a professional so i dont know what you mean exactly

Comment: Where is your main function?

Comment: Use a `std::string`. You're trying to read into a constant string that hasn't been allocated memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main(){

    ifstream script;
    script.open("main.py");
    // const char *programm; // You don't need a C string unless you have a reason.
    string programm;
    if (script.is_open()) {
        while (!script.eof()) {
            string line;
            script >> line;
            line += '\n';
            programm += line;
        }
    }
    script.close();
    // Now do your task with programm;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: how to convert string to char?

Comment: Oh! didn't noticed that :) You can't write into an input stream. Also operator stream operators don't work on arrays.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues. The main one (causing the error) is that in `C++` you can't just have code living on its own. It all goes into functions. In particular, you have to have the `main` function.

Also, your read loop is not going to work correctly. You should read into a `std::string`, that will keep track of the memory for you, and the current way you would miss the last string. I would suggest reading a line at a time. Something like this:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream script ("main.py");
    std::string line;
    if (!script) // Check the state of the file
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open file\n";
        return 1;
    }
    while (std::getline(script, line)) // Read a line at a time.
        // This also checks the state of script after the read.
    {
        // Do something with line
    }
    return 0; // File gets closed automatically at the end
}
```

Comment: You want the entire file in one string? That's a bit odd. You can just have another string called `file`, and do `file.push_back(line);` inside the loop. But this is not really a good idea. Presumably there is some interface to execute the python script within your program. Can you not do this just by passing the filename?

Comment: invite me into a chat please